# Using WYSIWYG FCKEditor with Groovy/Grails toolsuite

Tags: grails

I have installed FCKEditor plugin, can some one please tell me where to go next with it.
I am using Groovy/Grails toolsuite and would like to use WYSIWYG editor and build my .gsp pages with it.  How do I startup this editor in Groovy/Grails toolsuite IDE.

Comment: FCKEditor is an input field for use in forms and similar. Is not a gsp WYSIWYG editor